# How to use Restler Rest client library instead of Angular/HTTP

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, http-headers

I am using [Restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler) library as a Rest client on IONIC project to consume a Notejs API,
the goald is to use Restler instead of the Http service of Angularjs:

I tried this way:

```
let options = { headers: {'Authorization':[this.token]}};

restler.get('http://localhost:8083/api/auth/protected', JSON.stringify(options ) ).on('complete', function(result, response) {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
        reject(result);
    } else {
        resolve(result);
    }
});
```

this way return: result "Unauthorized"

the angular/Http way:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', this.token);

this.http.get('http://localhost:8083/api/auth/protected', {headers: headers})
         .subscribe(res => {
             resolve(res);
         }, (err) => {
             reject(err);
         });
```

and this returns : `{"_body":"{\"content\":\"Success\"}","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost:8083/api/auth/protected"}`

I have tried Restler get method to consume a restful API without parameter and it work, I think the parameter Options (headers) not correctly passed

Comment: i think the best way is to create an interceptor of your http request and set the header there (so you don't have to do it every request)

Comment: Take a look at your way of passing auth token, in restler way you make it with an array and in ng2 http you make it plain token. this is the difference imho. try changing it and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) as a Rest API client instead of using [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler)

I have tested and it work great, exactly as @angular/http service,

for example:

@angular/http implementation:

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8083/api/auth/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {

        resolve(data);

        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

       });
```

needle implementation:

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let options = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }

    needle.post('http://localhost:8083/api/auth/login', credentials, options, function(err, resp) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
                resolve(resp.body);
    }else{
      reject(err);

    }
    });
```